# How to define shapes for enumerate (myenum, myitem) in Beamer using Madrid theme

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize, bullets

How to define differents  bullet styles for enumerate (myenum) and itemize (myenum) in beamer, as you can see in my MWE there is only **bigsphere** i want to create an other shape like square or circle with different colors , here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}} % framebreaks without numbering
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]% align the frametitle to the right
%\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\graphicspath{{pics/}}
%
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\ar}{\textarabic} % to change the laguage in the section and frame title to persian
% This work as: \a{متن فارسی}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~define bullet for enumerate~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myenum}[1]
{
\par\vspace{3pt}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.8}\pgftext{\normalsize \pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
\pgftext{\usebeamerfont*{item projected}\textcolor{white}{#1}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~define bullet for itemize~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitem}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.1}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitemII}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.8}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%*************************************************************************
%\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying} %new code
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
\setRTL \myenum{\inserttocsectionnumber}
\inserttocsection\par
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\setRTL \myitem
\inserttocsubsection\par%
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{%
\setRTL \rightskip=3ex\myitem
\inserttocsubsection\par%
}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
%\selectlanguage{arabic}
\title{\textarabic{بعنوان عنوان نعنوان }}
\author{AUTHOR}
\date{\today}
%
\frame{\titlepage}
%
\frame{
\frametitle{\textarabic{فهرست مطالب}}
\begin{minipage}{1.\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}
\tableofcontents
\end{Arabic}
\end{minipage}
}
\section{\textarabic{مقدمه}}
\subsection{\textarabic{مایع }}
\subsubsection{\textarabic{مایع }}
{
\frametitle{\textarabic{سیستمهای فرمیونی همبسته:مایع}}
\begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}% ----------------------here must be changed
%
\begin{itemize}[label=\protect\myitemII, rightmargin=0mm]
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}

{متن فارسی .....}
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\end{itemize}

\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\myenum{\arabic*}]
\item
 \ar{نص عربي } 
\item
\ar{نص عربي }
\item
\ar{نص عربي }
\end{enumerate} 
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\end{Arabic}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use beamers own mechanism to switch between different itemize templates and colours:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}

\usepackage{tikzducks} % just for the last example

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\newcommand{\ar}{\textarabic} % to change the laguage in the section and frame title to persian

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}

{
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[default]
        \begin{itemize}
        \raggedleft
        \item \ar{متن فارسی .....}
        \end{itemize}
}

{
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[bullet]
        \begin{itemize}
        \raggedleft
        \item \ar{متن فارسی .....}
        \end{itemize}
}

{
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
    \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}
        \begin{itemize}
        \raggedleft
        \item \ar{متن فارسی .....}
        \end{itemize}
}

{
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[square]
        \begin{itemize}
        \raggedleft
        \item \ar{متن فارسی .....}
        \end{itemize}
}

{
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.15]
            \duck
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
        \begin{itemize}
        \raggedleft
        \item \ar{متن فارسی .....}
        \end{itemize}
}

\end{Arabic}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is great, but doesn't work in my case because I am using RTL language, so when i insert your answer, it shows just white space before items. please if you could help with how replace  ''bigsphere'' with square for example!

Comment: Last update of your answer is perfect, but solved one issue and causes other issues kike frame title is shifted to the left.

Comment: @AbdelhakElfengour Did you add the modifications of the frametitle from your not-so-minimal example? I removed them in my example because they are unrelated to the question, but if I add them back, the frametitle is right aligned.